# UIImagePickerController cannot push camera button in landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape

I want to get the solution about my problem.
My problem is that my app cannot take a picture in landscape mode.

I use UIImagePickerController in my app.
and in Portrait mode, it's okey
but in landscape mode, cannot push the camera button and cancel button.

if I rotate portrait mode, then I can push the buttons.
plz let me know the solution~
thanks~

iPhone 6 plus ios8.3 -> landscape, portrait both okey

iphone 5 ios8.1.2 -> landscape no, portrait okey

iphone 5s ios 8.1 -> landscape no, portrait okey

the code part that call UIImagePickerController

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePickController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickController.delegate=self;
imagePickController.allowsEditing=TRUE;
[((FFWebViewController*)[UIViewController currentViewController]) presentModalViewController:imagePickController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is this a sizing issue where the button is ending up off the screen or is it still visible and not working? If it's the sizing you need to include info on how you're currently handling sizing.

Comment: the camera button is stil visible. but I can't push that button in only landscape mode!! that's the problem

Comment: @user2809312 Why you can't push?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.
It's iOS version issue.

I update 8.1.1 -> 8.3 and 8.1 -> 8.3
then, I can take a picture in landscape mode.
is it 8.1 version issue?
I can not sure about it.

anyway... 8.3 version it's okey!!!